# Stanford CS193p - Changing font size in line with card count number?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, font-size, emoji

I'm on the final task for Assignment 1, "5. When your game randomly shows 5 pairs, the font we are using for the emoji will be too large (in portrait) and will start to get clipped. Have the font adjust in the 5 pair case (only) to use a smaller font than .largeTitle. Continue to use .largeTitle when there are 4 or fewer pairs in the game."

I've added the following code below I made, but cant figure out HOW to do it correctly. Any help greatly appreciated. New to coding for those super enough to answer!

```
struct ContentView: View {
var viewModel: EmojiMemoryGame

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        ForEach(viewModel.cards) { card in
            CardView(card: card).onTapGesture {
                self.viewModel.choose(card: card)
            }
// MARK: - Aspect Ratio 2/3
        }.aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
    }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
  //.font(Font.largeTitle).   To be deleted once the below is made successful

  //TODO: - Add font size to allow 5 pairs of cards not to clip on portrait view

  if numberOfPairsOfCards.count >=5 {
            .font(Font.footnote)
        } else {
            .font(Font.largeTitle)
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the ternary operator

```
struct ContentView: View {
var viewModel: EmojiMemoryGame

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        ForEach(viewModel.cards) { card in
            CardView(card: card).onTapGesture {
                self.viewModel.choose(card: card)
            }
            .aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
        }
    }
    .padding()
    .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
    .font(viewModel.cards.count == 10 ? Font.footnote : Font.largeTitle)
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was adding a parameter when initializing the ContentView, since I found that many things are not mutable inside the contentView. So I had a line in the SceneDelagate to handle the font type

```
let game = EmojiMemoryGame()
    var fontType: Font
    if game.cards.count == 10{
        fontType = Font.body
    } else {
        fontType = Font.largeTitle
    }
    let contentView = ContentView(game_viewModel: game, fontType: fontType)
```

And here's my ContentView Code

```
struct ContentView: View {
var game_viewModel: EmojiMemoryGame
var fontType: Font
var body: some View {
    let cardStack = HStack {
        ForEach(game_viewModel.cards) { card in
            CardView(card: card).onTapGesture{
                self.game_viewModel.choose(card: card)
            }
        }
    }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
        .font(fontType)
    return cardStack
}
}
```

Another way of doing it is by adding a function to update fonts:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var game_viewModel: EmojiMemoryGame
func updatefont() -> Font{
    if game_viewModel.cards.count == 10{
        return Font.body
    } else {
        return Font.largeTitle
    }
}
var body: some View {
    let cardStack = HStack {
        ForEach(game_viewModel.cards) { card in
            CardView(card: card).onTapGesture{
                self.game_viewModel.choose(card: card)
            }
        }
    }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
        .font(updatefont())
    return cardStack
}
}
```